# Android:how to get lat and long into my adapter

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to get latitude and longitude of a place when i enter my address. i have one activity with programatically created custom dailog, this has the address feilds, when i type my address i need to get the latitude and logitude. below is my adapter code where i am trying to get the lat and lng  details

```
 public void performAction(View v, final Activity activity) {


            Context myContext = v.getContext();
            PopUpMenu popUpMenu = (PopUpMenu) v.getTag();
            String result = popUpMenu.getMenuName();
            if (result != null
                    && result.equalsIgnoreCase(myContext.getResources().getString(
                            R.string.addnewplace))) {
                 AttractionData attractionData = new AttractionData();
   createDiloag(attractionData,activity.getResources().getString(R.string.addnewplace));
                setgpsLocation();

            }



        public void setgpsLocation() {

            final EditText address = new EditText(this.activity);
            String addressText = address.getText().toString();

            try {
                final StringBuffer myAddress = new StringBuffer();
                if(addressText!=null&&!addressText.trim().equals("")){
                    myAddress.append(addressText);
                }
                Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(parentActivity, Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocationName(addressText, 5);

                 if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {  

             Address location = addressList.get(0);
             location.getLatitude();
             location.getLongitude();

            // int lat = (int) (addressList.get(0).getLatitude() * 1e6);  
            // int lng = (int) (addressList.get(0).getLongitude() * 1e6);  



            AttractionData attractionData = new AttractionData();
             attractionData.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
             attractionData.setLongitude( location.getLongitude());


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error", e);
            }
        }
```

I am unable to get the lat lng details, Any help is appreciated.

Comment: On which line are you unable to get lat. and lng.? Did you check if "location.get" methods return null?

Comment: @SerdarS. getting the details but its not setting into feilds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is with the following lines:

```
final EditText address = new EditText(this.activity);
String addressText = address.getText().toString();
```

You `addressText` will be an empty string every time because you're creating a new EditText instead of using the one from the existing activity.

Try to replace it with:

```
final EditText address = (EditText)this.activity.findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text_id);
```

and replace `your_edit_text_id` with the id in your layout file.

---

If you created your view programmatically then provide a getter for it.

In your activity:

```
public EditText getAddressEditText() {
    return this.mAddressEditText;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
final EditText address = this.activity.getAddressEditText();
```

Comment: @bbalazs...i am programatically creating the edittext..i dont have any layout file.

Comment: Then you need to create a getter for it in your activity and use this.activity.getAddressEditText().

Comment: why dont put EditText address as a field in your class? is more easy than create it as final.

Comment: Fernando: yes, you can do that, too. You can also pass the EditText as an argument to the performAction method, etc. There are a lot you can do. :) The point was: he was missing the text.